# mongo shell edit query with external editor: strange chars in Windows

Tags: mongodb, shell, encoding, mongo-shell

I've added the line to my .mongorc.js:

```
var EDITOR = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
```

When I run `edit q` from mongo shell it opens notepad with the following content:

[image: screenshot of notepad]

Same thing happens with vim. The editing works just OK, i.e. if I remove the line and write what I need, it's passed to shell properly.

Any ideas on how to get rid of that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the `undefined` part, the reason is that you have no content in what you are trying to edit.

If you follow the section as described in the [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/mongo/#can-i-edit-long-shell-operations-with-an-external-text-editor):

Define a function myFunction

```
function myFunction() {}
```

Then edit with your editor:

```
edit myFunction
```

Everything will work as expected. So the problem was your `q` thingy was not defined, hence the output.

The other characters are likely a system code page issue. I'm not sure if interaction with the shell expects ANSI or whether UTF-8 is okay. But anything else or UTF-16 might cause the issue. Hard to tell without knowing what language setting you have, etc.

Comment: Here's what I have in editor: `[35mfunction myFunction() {}[m`. There is some problem with encoding, I guess.

Comment: @voru yes, looks like encoding. If you try `Save As` from the menu in notepad what does the **ENCODING** part say? But I'm generally guessing it's to do with the code page on your system

Comment: vim says `utf-8[dos]`

Comment: @vorou Actually came across something. Do you have some type of colorizing thing happening in your command prompt shell? Those escape codes seem to be something to do with that.